# How to queue up a set of raw audio files from bash

Tags: linux, bash, gstreamer, vlc

I am using a system that is pushing out raw audio files in the tmp directory that I want to play.  My Linux distro has some bug that causes a pause for two seconds every time you play some audio with a utility (eg mplayer, sox, etc).  As a workaround, I want to continuously play the audio files without this pause.

I have very little control over the system.  The system will be up whenever the computer is on but files will come through in bursts.  The system creates the files, runs a script that you specify and then deletes the file.  I could move the file, convert it, whatever, but I want it to be simple and elegant.  I'm thinking there would be some way to push the files into a queue that will play the file without closing the session to the sound card so I don't get that annoying delay.

I'm thinking something like GStreamer or VLC could work.  Any suggestions?

Update:  If you vote to close this question, please tell me exactly why.  THIS IS A PROGRAMMING QUESTION for the bash programming language..plain and simple.

Comment: "My Linux distro has some bug" [citation needed]

Comment: You should post a bug report on the distro's tracker and see how that goes :).

Comment: I am also looking into a fix for this bug, but a workaround using bash as described above is the reason for this particular post.  I'm thinking there is a simple workaround that I can apply in a few minutes without needing some driver or kernel patches.

Comment: I'm not aware of this "bug" in your distro.  Can you point us to the bug report?  Also, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I hesitate on sharing this link because my post is a programming question, but here's the bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/702562.  Please don't try to address the bug on this post because then someone will close this question altogether.  Please, does anyone have a bash script that could play a queue of files without closing the session to the sound driver?

Comment: What audio output path is MPlayer using? I've seen this problem before in assorted Linux audio apps.

Comment: @Mike:  I'm not sure, how can I find out?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using VLC because you can enqueue files using a shell-script that calls the command-line interface of VLC http://wiki.videolan.org/Console

Gstreamer itself is not suited for playlist-style apps out of the box - for a gstreamer based solution you better use a player that uses gstreamer as backend. But try VLC for that first.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  However, VLC does not properly play the files for some reason.  If I just run `cvlc testfile.wav`, it chops off the last .5 second or so.  I also tried mplayer with the -idle switch but the process stops if there is inactivity for some extended period of time.  Any other programs you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it is possible with plain gst-launch but you can do this with python and pygst.
Just handle `MESSAGE_EOS` and update `uri` property with next file.

Here is modified code from [pygst tutorial](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/playbin.html) Example 2.3 (which does what you want but adds ~0.5s delay between files):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
import glib, gobject
import pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst

class CLI_Main:  
  def __init__(self):
    self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "player")
    fakesink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink")
    self.player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)
    bus = self.player.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message", self.on_message)

    self.currentFile = 1
    self.play(self.currentFile)

  def play(self, n):
      filePath = "file://" + sys.argv[n]
      self.player.set_property("uri", filePath)
      self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

  def on_message(self, bus, message):
    t = message.type
    if t == gst.MESSAGE_EOS:
      self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
      self.currentFile += 1 
      if self.currentFile < len(sys.argv):
        self.play(self.currentFile)
      else:
        loop.quit()

    elif t == gst.MESSAGE_ERROR:
      self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
      err, debug = message.parse_error()
      print "Error: %s" % err, debug
      loop.quit()

mainclass = CLI_Main()
gobject.threads_init()
loop = glib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little python application using gstreamer with the playbin2 element. Playbin2 supports gapless playback, where you can prepare the next file white one is playing.  Playing multiple files from a script using player command invocation will natually cause gaps unless the command enques the files to a running instance.